# The telegram bot should delete Sticker, Gif, and Voice that are sent to the group;but do not delete them

Tags: python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

I built a telegram bot with a python-telegram-bot module.I added the bot to the group and got the bot in the admin group.The bot should be delete when Sticker, Gif or Voice are sent to the group;But the bot does not delete them.bot code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

def sticker_method(bot, update):
    bot.delete_sticker(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, sticker_id = update.sticker.chat_id)
    bot.delete_gif(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, gif_id = update.gif.chat_id)
    bot.delete_voice(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, voice_id = update.voice.chat_id)


def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, sticker_method))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# for exit
# updater.idle()
```

There is no error during execution;But the bot does nothing!

Answer (score 0):

There are no `delete_sticker`, `delete_gif` nor `delete_voice` methods in this library. What you are looking for is [`bot.delete_message()`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.delete_message).

Also you can use some extensive filters, for example [`Filters.sticker`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.sticker) and [`Filters.voice`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.voice).

More Info (Edited):

For example you can do (with the usage of [`Filters.sticker`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.sticker) and [`Message.delete()`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.delete)):

```
def delete_sticker_callback(bot, update):
    update.message.delete()


def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, delete_sticker_callback))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: My English language is not good and I can not read the pages that you said, please correct my code

Comment: I updated the answer to contain a minimal example on deleting a message upon receiving messages of a certain type.